# Rank of eigenvector projections

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank, projection-matrices

Consider the following two $n\times n$ matrices:

$$A_1:=H_1\Sigma_1H_1' $$

$$A_2:=H_2\Sigma_2H_2'$$

where $\Sigma_1$,$\Sigma_2$ are positive definite $k\times k$ matrices ($k<n$), and $H_1$,$H_2$ are $n\times k$ matrices such that

$$H_1'H_1=H_2'H_2=I_k \hspace{1cm}\text{and} \hspace{1cm} H_1'H_2=\begin{bmatrix}
I_r & 0 \\
0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix} .$$

Now I perform the eigendecomposition of $A_1$ and $A_2$ (with eigenvalues in decreasing order and orthonormal eigenvectors), but keep only the first $k$ eigenvectors  of $A_1$ and the first $s$ eigenvectors $(s>k)$ of $A_2$. Let $U_1$ and $U_2$ be the $n\times k$ and $n\times s$ matrices of eigenvectors for $A_1$ and $A_2$ respectively. I want to show that the matrix

$$U_1-U_2U_2'U_1=MU_1$$

has rank $n-r$, where $M:=I_n-U_2U'_2$. This is similar to [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2719322/522332), but the columns of $H_1$ and $H_2$ are not fully independent.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can we assume that eigenvectors selected for each matrix are an orthonormal set?

Comment: @BenGrossmann Yes. I will add it.

Comment: A possibly helpful step: from the information given, we can necessarily partition the matrices $H_i$ into 
$$
H_i = [J_0 \ \ J_i], \quad i = 1,2
$$
where $J_0$ has size $n \times r$, $J_i$ has size $n \times (k-r)$, $J_1'J_2 = J_2'J_1 = 0$.

Comment: If we divide the $\Sigma_i$ into blocks of the shape
$$
\pmatrix{r \times r & r \times (k-r)\\ (k-r)\times r & (k-r)\times(k-r)},
$$
then we can expand the $A_i$ into sums in terms of these $J_i$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Yes. $H_1-H_2H_2'H_1=[0 \, \, J_1]$ which has rank $n-r$. Am trying to understand why this remains true if $H_i$ is replaced by $U_i$ $i=1,2$.

Comment: Ah, just straightened it all out. It simply comes down to the fact that the column space of $U_1$ is equal to that of $H_1$.

Comment: Are you sure that it remains true, or is this just an empirical observation?

Comment: @BenGrossmann It is an empirical observation indeed. If $s<k$ then it seems to fail.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Can you expand on why $U_1$ and $H_1$ share the same column space?

Comment: Both column spaces are simply the column space of $A_1$. For $U_1$, it's clear that the column space of $A_1$ is spanned by its non-zero eigenvalues. For $H_1$, note that $A_1$ has rank $k$ but is of the form $H_1 B$ for some matrix $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns of $U_1$ form an orthonormal basis for the column space of $A_1$, which is in turn the column space of $H_1$. Let $S_1$ denote this column space.

The columns of $U_2$ form an orthonormal basis for the sum of the column space of $A_2$ and an arbitrary $(s-k)$-dimensional subspace of $\ker(A_2)$. Let $S_2$ denote the column space of $U_2$.

From the construction of $A_1$ and $A_2$, we know that the intersection of the column spaces of $A_1$ and $A_2$ is $r$-dimensional (in particular, it is equal to the column space of the matrix $J_0$ defined in the comments on your question). Let $S_0$ denote this intersection.

The rank of $(I - U_2U_2')U_1$ is equal to $\dim(S_1) - \dim(S_1 \cap S_2)$. Because $S_0 \subseteq S_2$, the dimension of this intersection is at most equal to
$$
\dim(S_1) - \dim(S_0) = k - r.
$$
However, if $S_0 \subsetneq S_2$, then this rank will be strictly smaller. In other words, if the arbtirary $(s-k)$-dimensional subspace of $\ker(A_2)$ has a non-trivial intersection with the column space of $A_1$, then the rank will be less than $k-r$.

If this $(s-k)$-dimensional subspace is "randomly" selected, then the probability of a non-trivial intersection occurring by chance is extremely small, which would explain your empirical results.

---

**Illustrative counterexample:**
$$
H_1 = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1\\0&0\\0&0}, \quad H_2 = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0\\0&1\\0&0}, \Sigma_1 = \Sigma_2 = \pmatrix{2&0\\0&1}.
$$
Note that the following is possible:
$$
U_1 = H_1, \quad U_2 = \pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&1&0\\0&0&0}.
$$
We compute
$$
(I - U_2U_2')U_1 = \pmatrix{0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1} \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1\\0&0\\0&0} = 0,
$$
which has rank smaller than $k - r = 2 - 1 = 1$. On the other hand, if you take the final column of $U_2$ to be a "random" unit vector from the set $\{(0,x_2,0,x_4): x_2,x_4 \in \Bbb C\}$, you should find that the matrix $(I - U_2U_2')U_1$ has rank $1$ in practically all cases.

Comment: Sorry for this late reply. I have been studying your answer carefully but I can't figure out the claim about the rank of $(I - U_2U_2')U_1$. Could you expand on that?

Comment: @Alphie I never got around to addressing your question, sorry about that. Are you still confused about my claim?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I asked the question at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4012673/522332. It seems that the rank of $(I - U_2U_2')U_1$ is not equal to $\dim(S_1 \cap S_2^\perp)$ in general, but it is equal to $\dim(S_1) - \dim(S_1 \cap S_2)$, which is what we need.

Comment: Well, glad it worked out in some way