# Rank of projection error

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality, matrix-rank, projection-matrices

Let $X_1$,$X_2$ be $n\times k$ real matrices with rank $k$. Let $S_1,S_2$ denote the column spaces of $X_1,X_2$ respectively. I am trying to show that the rank of $MX_1 $, with $M:=I_n-X_2(X_2'X_2)^{-1}X'_2$, equals the dimension of $S_1 \cap S_2^\perp$.

I know that the matrix above is the error arising from the projection of each column of $X_1$ on $S_2$, but don't know where to go from there. I notice that we have $X_2'MX_1=0$.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure about $MX_1$, but $M$ itself seems nice. If $v\in S_2$, i.e., $v=X_2 u$ for some vector $u$, then $$Mv=v-X_2(X_2'X_2)^{-1} X_2' X_2u=v-X_2 u=0.$$ By contrast, if $v\in S_2^\perp$ then $X_2'v=0$ and $Mv=v$. So $M$ annihilates vectors in $S_2$ but acts as the identity on vectors in $S_2^\perp$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think what you're saying is true. Define $X_1,X_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 1}$ by $$X_1=(1,0)^T$$ $$X_2=(1,1)^T$$ Then $S_1$ is the $x-$ axis, $S_2$ is the line $y=x$, and $S_2^{\perp}$ is the line $y=-x$. Notice $S_1 \cap S_2^{\perp}=\{(0,0)^T\}$ has dimension $0$. On the other hand, your $2\times 1$ matrix $MX_1=(0.5,-0.5)^T$ has rank $1$.

Comment: I see. What if I also assume that $X'_1X_1=X'_2X_2=I_k$ ?
 Can I show it in this case?

Comment: No. If you replace $X_2$ with $\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\bigg)^T$ then $X_2^TX_2=X_1^TX_1=1$ but you still get $\dim(S_1 \cap S_2^{\perp})=0,\text{rank}(MX_1)=1$

Comment: Ah then I can I show that the rank equals $\dim(S_1) - \dim(S_1 \cap S_2)$? This seems to work here

Comment: Yes. Apply rank nullity to $T:S_1 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $T(x)=\text{Proj}_{S_2^{\perp}}(x)$

Comment: The null space of $T$ is $S_1\cap S_2$. Therefore by the rank-nullity theorem the rank of $T$ must be $\dim(S_1) - \dim(S_1 \cap S_2)$ correct?

Comment: Looks good to me. All you have to do now to finish your argument is show that the range of $T$ is the range of the linear transformation $$x \longrightarrow MX_1x$$ But this is fairly obvious.

Comment: Right, but that is because $T(x)=Mx$ and $S_1=\{X_1 x : x\in \mathbb{R}^n\}$, so $T(S_1)=\{MX_1 x : x\in \mathbb{R}^n\}$ right?